# Does $a \leq b + c $ imply $a^2 \leq (b+c)^2 + (b-c)^2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

Givens
$$
a \leq b + c 
$$
or 
$$
a^2 \leq b^2 + c^2+2bc 
$$
Can we prove that?: 
$$
a^2 \leq (b+c)^2 + (b-c)^2 = 2b^2 + 2c^2
$$

Comment: Not in general. Let $a<0$  and $b,c=0$. Then your first inequality holds but the second doesn't. Perhaps you mean for positive $a$?

Comment: $a\le b+c$ and $a^2 \leq b^2 + c^2+2bc$ are only equivalent if $b+c\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$a^2 \leq b^2+c^2 + 2bc= (b+c)^2,$$

then

$$a^2 \leq (b+c)^2 + (b-c)^2$$

as $(b-c)^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(b-c)^2\geq0$$

therefore $$b^2+c^2\geq 2bc$$

Hence $$2b^2+2c^2\geq b^2+c^2+2bc\geq a^2$$

But the problem is that the very first inequality $b+c\geq a$ doesn't tell us if $a$ is non-negative. It is possible that $b+c\geq a$ but $a$ is very negative like $a=-\sqrt{(b^2+c^2)+1}$, while $b,c\geq0$. Then $b+c\geq0\geq a$ but $a^2=b^2+c^2+1>b^2+c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a\geq0$, it is easy to see that $a\leq b+c$ means also that $a^2\leq (b+c)^2$. Your inequality follows by adding the positive terms $(b-c)^2$.

If $a<0$, you can't say anything...

**Edit for updated question**:

Your second condition $a^2\leq b^2+c^2 + 2bc$ already is enough to prove the final relation, since $b^2+c^2+2bc = (b+c)^2$. Combine this with $(b-c)^2\geq 0$ and you're done

Comment: Hmm... well you changed the question now...